# How to create a dropdown list with data from my mysql database?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

So, I have an html form where the user will select some options. I want to create a dropdown list, in which the data we will be coming from my mysql database.
These are my files:
[image]

Ignore the other files. Index.html is my home page and my form is at air-tickets.html

**air-tickets.html**

```
<form id="form-submit" method="post">
    <div class="container" id="air-form-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="sel2" class="dropbar-label">Airline: </label>
            <select class="form-control airline-select" id="sel2" name="airline">
                <option value="none">Select airline</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**air_tickets.js**

```
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var air_tickets_router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var db = require('../database');

air_tickets_router.use(bodyParser.json());

air_tickets_router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile('air-tickets.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });
    })
    .post(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.body.sellist1);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.redirect('/air-tickets');
    });

air_tickets_router.get('/get_airlines', function(req, res, next) {
    var sql = 'SELECT airline FROM flight ORDER BY airline';
    db.query(sql, function(err, data, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('airline-list', { title: 'Airline List', userData: data });
    });
});

module.exports = air_tickets_router;
```

**database.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "myuser",
    password: "mypassword",
    database: "myproject",
    multipleStatements: true
});

mysqlConnection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database is connected successfully !');
});

module.exports = mysqlConnection;
```

**And the app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

const mysqlConnection = require("./database")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Require routes
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var air_ticketsRouter = require('./routes/air_tickets');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Use the routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/air-tickets', air_ticketsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Also I have this air_tickets_form.js in public-->js file**

```
const airlineSelect = document.querySelector("#sel2");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/air-tickets/get_airlines')

    .then(req => req.json())
        .then(res => {
            for (let airline of res) {
                let airlineOption = document.createElement("option");
                console.log(airline);
                airlineOption.value = airline;
                airlineOption.innerHTML = airline;
                airlineSelect.appendChild(airlineOption);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you could add an `<option>` to your select in javascript like this:

```
function addOption() {
  var select = document.getElementById("sel2"); //get your <select> by its ID
  var option = document.createElement("option"); // create a New <option>
  option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Airline Name")); // provide <option> Text 
  option.setAttribute("id", "yourOptionID"); // giving your <option> an id
  select.appendChild(option); // add the created <option> to your <select>
}
```

Now you only have to loop through your Database Results and add `options` as described

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can approach this problem using 2 methods :

1 - First Method (Not recommended)
You can wait for your HTML page to load , then run Javascript to fetch your data and convert it to Options under the select Tag

This is exactly what your air_tickets_form.js is doing, all you need is to include this file inside your html

just add this line at the end of your body

```
<script src="./js/air_tickets_form.js"></script>
```

and express will serve this file from the static folder "Public"

Disadvantage : your website will load and for few seconds, the list will be empty
if the fetch request failed , then it will remain empty until reload

2 - Second Method (Recommended)
Use the Render Engine
within your app.js - i can see that you use Render Engine
in this line

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Jade became old, and replaced now with pug
You can install it using NPM
then replace this line with this

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
```

Now you are using the view engine

then you need to convert your html to PUG Syntax

for now you can use online converter such as this one
https://html-to-pug.com/

but I recommend you to read Pug Documentation to understand how the syntax is working
(Be caution that spaces count is important in pug )

and when you want to send the HTML file , you send the pug file instead using this code

```
res.render('index.pug' , data)
```

as data is your air tickets data

then inside your Pug file , at the select tag , you will want to make a loop that insert the HTML Automatically

```
form#form-submit(method='post')
  #air-form-container.container
    .col-md-12
      label.dropbar-label(for='sel2') Airline: 
      select#sel2.form-control.airline-select(name='airline')
        option(value='none') Select airline
          each val,index in data
            option(value=index) #{val}
```

the `each` function will loop in the data and then add the line below it for each data

Advantage : Your website will load with all the data ready to use without waiting

Another approach you can use is to Mix between the two methods - use the render engine to make the data ready

and make a button when pressed it will refresh the data using js

of course according to your need.